# how to run a command in command prompt as admin using c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, command-prompt, administrator

I want to run a command in command prompt with c#.net application and I want command prompt as admin so how can I run below command in command prompt

the command to register dll in windows:

```
C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe zkemkeeper.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step by step how to do it in Visual Studio. I'm taking into account you know how to create a [Setup Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx) for your solution.

1. Add a [**Setup Project**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx) to the solution.
2. Right-click on the Setup Project, go on **Add** then **Assembly**.
3. Browse for your COM assembly (.dll) and add it to your Setup Project.
4. After adding the assembly, right-click on it in **Solution Explorer** and click **Properties**.
5. Look for "Register" property and set it to `vsdraCOM`.

Now, when you run your setup installer, the DLL will be registered on the installed machine.